# Microsoft Velocity - best way to share cached data on single server

Tags: asp.net, wcf, caching, appfabric

I have several WCF services and ASP.NET application both accessing data via shared service layer. Inside this layer I'm performing all required data access and caching. Now I need to share cached object between WCF ans ASP.NET. What's the best way to configure Velocity to work on a SINGLE server. Also how can I disable object serialization?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the best way? Do you mean choosing between storing the cluster configuration in a shared folder or in SQL Server?
AFAIK if you disable object serialisation, you won't be able to store any object in Velocity or IIRC the ASP.NET cache - you have to be able to serialise an object to cache it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Velocity is designed to provide a **distributed** cache. If you only have a single server MS Velocity may be a bit overkill.

Another point against using MS Velocity is that it is still in CTP.

In your case I would use MS Enterprise Library Caching Application Block. If you set up your ASP:net and your WCF site to use the same application pool they will have access to the same memory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx

Comment: Is it correct, that application running in the same AppPool has shared ASP.NET Cache object?

Comment: The Enterprise Library Cache not the ASP.Net Cache. The Entlib cache is a singleton, both applications access the same memory, therefore, they should both have access to the same singleton.